# How can I protect a room from bugs without using mosquito-nets or visible barriers?

Tags: mosquitoes

Is there a way to protect a room from mosquitoes, I am looking for something I can use which does not change the way the room looks from the outside.

Comment: Close the window?  Does a window count as visible?  Not sure what kind of answer you're looking for.

Comment: It is a small room which needs to be kept open at night. For the purpose of circulating its air. After a few hours of being closed it really becomes difficult even to breath. The problem are the mosquitoes and I cannot install mosquito nets because of regulations

Comment: That sounds like some very silly regulations.  Do they give a reason?  Do you mean you are not allowed to put a screen in the window, or not allowed to use [mosquito netting](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Mosquito_Netting.jpg) to protect oneself while asleep?

Comment: It is not permitted to put a screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Screens are the best solution, and the only solution guaranteed to keep your room 100% bug free (as long as people are careful not to let them in at the door).

Other preventative methods include using mosquito deterrents or repellents like citronella candles, torches, lanterns, etc. There are brands devoted to mosquito control like [Thermacell](https://www.thermacell.com/) who provide a plethora of products.

Your next best solution is to control the mosquito population in your yard. Preventative methods work the best, by either eliminating breeding areas such as anything that can collect water (spare tires, buckets or pails, ditches that perpetually puddle, swampy areas, etc.), mosquitoes will breed wherever there is standing water. Some mosquitos lay eggs in grass too, keep your grass cut and don't let any areas of you yard get overgrown. Long grass is a haven for mosquitos because they can fly down where they have protection from sun and heat, and also often find water.

Finally, you can treat your yard and kill all the mosquitos before they become a problem. Larvicide any pools, fountains, or ponds that you have in your yard. This kills 99% of the larvae before they mature. Malathion is most popular for killing mature mosquitos in your yard. You can get a bottle with a hose attachment and spray your yard, or you can get a fogger from pretty much any hardware store and fog your yard. Do this the morning of or the night before your event and you're pretty  much guaranteed to not have any bug problems that night.

Answer (score 2):

[The CDC recommends...](https://www.cdc.gov/zika/prevention/prevent-mosquito-bites.html)

> Take steps to control mosquitoes inside and outside your home
>
> - Use screens on windows and doors. Repair holes in screens to keep mosquitoes outside.
> - Use air conditioning when available.
> - Sleep under a mosquito bed net if air conditioned or screened rooms are not available or if sleeping outdoors.
> - Once a week, empty and scrub, turn over, cover, or throw out items that hold water, such as tires, buckets, planters, toys, pools, birdbaths, flowerpots, or trash containers. Check inside and outside your home. Mosquitoes lay eggs near water.

Air conditioning and/or bug nets are used in many parts of the world to protect against mosquitoes.

Answer (score 1):

Mint oil.  Mint oil is fatal to all mosquitoes. Some on a rag here & there or mix it with lamp oil & burn it in a lamp.  There are also mosquito coils you can burn at night.

Comment: According to this https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10534958 only high concentrations of it can repel mosquitoes, and only if applied directly to the skin which can be irritating.

Comment: I burn it in a lamp on the veranda at night setting out. Put upwind. About 1 oz mint oil to a quart of oil. Works well Philippines. Live up above a river with down hill jungle below house. Also a rag stuffed Viena sausage  can with mint oil on it under a table will keep them away from a table.  Use often. This is local Philippine wild mint extract. Grows in vacant lots were I live.